# Is it possible to subscribe to browser notifications from the CLI?

Tags: push-notification

I have spent hours trying to find out anything about *consuming* browser notifications, but I literally couldn't find anything at all. Is there a way, from a CLI application, to subscribe to a service that pushes web notifications? I have looked into the browser API and everything, but I can't figure out or find any resources on how to, or whether it is possible to consume these notifications.

My goal is to write a Telegram bot that will subscribe to one of those services that pushes notifications, read the notifications, evaluate them and potentially message me.

The reason I want to do this is because the website does support sending me a certain amount of information, but I only want to be notified of some of that.